# Stuck with grub rescue and can't enter in BIOS

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, bios, grub

I have dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu and I've deleted Ubuntu and now I'm stuck with 
 `error: no such partition.`
 `Entering rescue mode...` 
 `grub rescue>` 
 I read that I have to enter in BIOS before grub loads up but I can't even do that (I pressed `F2`, `F10`, `F12`, `Delete` but it's hopeless). 
 I've tried to work with `ls` and `set` in grub rescue but with no success. Is there any way I can fix that or should I buy another HDD? I don't really mind losing data but don't want to buy anything for laptop just yet.

Comment: You didn't remove Ubuntu properly. GRUB is still your default bootloader and it's missing its files which were on Ubuntu's partition. Is your system set up using UEFI or CSM? If you don't know, do you remember (at least roughly) your partition layout? Did you follow any guide that told you to disable Secure Boot? Have you reinstalled Windows by yourself on this computer? What computer model is this? (laptop model or desktop motherboard model)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is UEFI, never seen CSM during installation. I only deleted Ubuntu through Disk Management in Windows 10 (silly me). My laptop is Lenovo G580 from 2012.

Comment: Just want to point out that GRUB cannot disable BIOS/UEFI configuration access. You are either pressing the wrong keys or not pressing them soon enough.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe If fast boot is enabled in UEFI, accessing setup may be impossible. I think it may even skip keyboard initialization, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @gronostaj I've accessed setup with fast boot enabled, so it must not usually skip keyboard init. It *is* hard and sometimes takes me several reboots.

Answer (score 5):

If your system is set up to boot with UEFI, then you should be able to access BIOS (or actually UEFI setup) from GRUB rescue prompt using the `fwsetup` command.

Once in UEFI setup, you should remove boot option for GRUB. This will restore Windows Boot Loader as the default bootloader.

Comment: I get unknown command when I type `fwsetup`

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution...but try to remove battery on your motherboard or reset settings on it, than it will load all default setting back. You should be able to recover, but that is not best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I fixed it.

First I removed all HDDs and SSDs so you will boot into BIOS. From there reset all setting in the BIOS  to factory.

After that, shutdown and plug all your drives back in. Now you should boot up like normally.